# chkrootkit - display only warnings

Tags: linux

Is there an option for `chkrootkit` to display only warnings - not the whole list what was checked and found to be "not infected", "not found", "nothing found", etc...

The manpage does not disclose such an option (at least I did not find one there, and it is rather short).

Comment: Did you try the `-q` (quiet) option?

Comment: Good point, thank you (I considered "quiet" to actually mean quiet). However, the information displayed with `-q` lacks the "what". To understand "not tested", I have to run `chkrootkit` again and look for "not tested". Same for the long list of hidden files...

If there are better options, I am grateful. Otherwise, `-q` must do...